# Could not load type from assembly - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error when adding middleware for MVC to ASP.NET Core solution

System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly 
'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

```
Line 26:          public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
Line 27:          {
Line 28:              services.AddMvc();
Line 29:              services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
Line 30:              services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>();

 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddOptions(IServiceCollection services) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services, Action<MvcOptions> setupAction) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services, Action<MvcOptions> setupAction) 
at OdeToFood2.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\aindriu\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\OdeToFood2\src\OdeToFood2\Startup.cs:line 28
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IServiceCollection exportServices) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

My dependencies in the project.json file are

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0",
    "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "4.0.0-rc3-309"
  },
```

Is there a conflict between different versions in the json file ?

here is my solution -

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10629841/OdeToFood2.zip

Comment: Did you try replacing all the RC{1,2,3} .NET Core dependencies with 1.0.0?

Comment: I replaced two but no change   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",

Answer (score 2):

I created a brand new web api application using "yo aspnet" and have the following project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
```

In order to get what you were after I had to add both the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core and Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.

Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: I think there is a mix up between AspNetCore and ASPNet.  ITs a bit confusing but nothing working yet when I use the above dependencies

Comment: So if you remove all the dependencies you had and add those above in is it still failing?

Comment: I had to create a new project & got it working.  I couldn't figure out what the problem was but I think it was a clash between ASP.NET and ASP.NET CORE 1.0 - I think they both do something similar but I made some kind of cross over.

Comment: It could well be the case. I got that working creating a brand new project too. Glad you got that working!

Answer (score 1):

Could you be missing in your project.json one of these two?

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection":"1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions":"1.0.0",
```

Comment: have you run dotnet restore after adding them in and still the same error?

Comment: yes I ran dotnet restore but still the same error.  I seem to have middleware problems with this solution but have the correct NuGet packages installed and can't see what the problem is ?

Comment: Have you tried using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc v1.0.0 package instead of the rc1-final? I just ran "yo aspnet" and I have all stable versions for a brand new web API application. Maybe you need to upgrade?

Comment: I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 1.0.0 installed.  I tried adding middleware like  //    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
          //  app.UseDefaultFiles();
          //  app.UseStaticFiles(); but I keep getting messages saying I don't have a definition.....ive added the solution, its small

Comment: I just tested it and could use "app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();". I have both Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core libraries. I had to run dotnet restore and it worked. I found that in the documentation the method in question https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions/index.html?highlight=usemvcwithdefaultroutes so it should be there

Comment: too long, I will add another answer